# Retrieving website xml with Excel

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel2003 I am trying to retrieve some content from Yahoo finance.

I have a really simple sub so far:

```
Public Sub test(BaseRange As Range)

    Dim xmlObject As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument

    With xmlObject
        Call .Open("GET", "http://biz.yahoo.com/research/earncal/20110923.html", False)
        Call .send
    End With


    With ActiveSheet.Range("F2")
        .Value = xmlObject.responseXML.XML
    End With

End Sub
```

The sub executes without errors and  the xmlObject.responseText seems to contain the page html text, but xmlObject.responseXml.XML is empty. Apart from resonsetext everything is actually empty.

What am I missing here?

Comment: There's only content in responsexml if the server returns an XML response.  Seems like your URL returns HTML and not XML.

Comment: Ah, right I see. I thought that the xml was generated from the html content. Thanks. If you put this comment as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only content in responseXml if the server returns an XML response. Seems like your URL returns HTML and not XML.

Answer (score 2):

It is worth pointing out that there is an open source project that does this already: 
http://excel-dna.net/2011/04/28/financial-analytics-suite-finansu-made-with-excel-dna/

I hope that this is useful to you

Comment: That looks pretty nifty, thanks for the tip :) This is actually just a pointless task I set myself to improve my coding skills, so I'm looking to develop a solution from scratch for this one.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used for the ECB FX rate.

```
Sub ecb_fx()
ActiveWorkbook.XMLIMPORT url:= _

        "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist.xml", ImportMap:=Nothing, _
        Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("$B$6")
End Sub
```